# How to Mock a Predicate in a Function using Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I want to mock Find method which expects a predicate using Moq:

```
public PurchaseOrder FindPurchaseOrderByOrderNumber(string purchaseOrderNumber)
    {
        return purchaseOrderRepository.Find(s => s.PurchaseOrderNumber ==    purchaseOrderNumber).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

My repository method

```
IList<TEntity> Find(Func<TEntity, bool> where);
```

I used following test method

```
[TestMethod]
  public void CanGetPurchaseOrderByPurchaseOrderNumber()
 {

      _purchaseOrderMockRepository.Setup(s => s.Find(It.IsAny<Func<PurchaseOrder, bool>>()).FirstOrDefault())
          .Returns((Func<PurchaseOrder, bool> expr) => FakeFactory.GetPurchaseOrder());

      _purchaseOrderService.FindPurchaseOrderByOrderNumber("1111");


 }
```

It gives me the following error:

> ServicesTest.PurchaseOrderServiceTest.CanGetPurchaseOrderByPurchaseOrderNumber
>   threw     exception: 
>        System.NotSupportedException: Expression references a  method that does not belong to the    mocked object: s =>
>   s.Find(It.IsAny()).FirstOrDefault

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer :)

I changed the test as follows and removed the call to FirstOrDefault:

```
[TestMethod]
  public void CanGetPurchaseOrderByPurchaseOrderNumber()
 {

      _purchaseOrderMockRepository.Setup(s => s.Find(It.IsAny<Func<PurchaseOrder, bool>>()))
          .Returns((Func<PurchaseOrder, bool> expr) => new List<PurchaseOrder>() {FakeFactory.GetPurchaseOrder()});

      _purchaseOrderService.FindPurchaseOrderByOrderNumber("1111");

      _purchaseOrderMockRepository.VerifyAll();


 }
```

Comment: A little late in the game, but this just helped me a good bit.  Thanks!